# Invalid signature of SAML Logout response from Azure AD in Keycloak

Tags: azure-active-directory, keycloak, saml-2.0

I'm getting invalid signature while validating the logout response in keycloak. Logout is happening in Azure Ad but not on keycloak. I have enabled the "validate signature" feature in keycloak.

SAML Sign-in working as expected

SAML Sign-out : Not working properly. Sign out is happening in azure side but the SAML response from Azure might have invalid signature which causing signature verification failed in keycloak side.

[image]

Application Id in Azure : 2992a9ae-dd8c-478d-9d7e-eb36ae903acc

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1184652/invalid-signature-of-saml-logout-response-in-keycl

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly, Azure encodes the URI escaping in lowercase characters which can cause some issues. Some implementations re-encode the URI into uppercase before checking the signature. If you have the ability to grab the original query, it should have the original lowercase escaping. If you can use a post for the logout response that might work better than a redirect